# Android FASTBOOT via USB OTG?

Tags: android, windows, adb, drivers, fastboot

I have a windows 8.1 tablet that only has a mircoUSB connector.
I've installed adb & fastboot drivers.

If I connect my Nexus tablet to my Windows tablet via OTG & USB Cables, it's detected fine when the Nexus tablet is booted normally.

I can run adb and browse the Nexus table without issue.

However if I reboot the Nexus tablet to the bootloader and then connect it to the Windows tablet, I get a quick connection sound and an instant disconnection.
Nothing appears in Device Manager.

Same Nexus tablet on a Windows 7 laptop or Windows 8.1 PC works fine in bootloader mode.

So what am I doing wrong on the Windows 8.1 tablet ?
Should this work via OTG ?

Is it a driver issue ? if it is how do I install the driver when nothing appears in device manager ?

Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote ? I'm asking if it's possible and if it should work with an OTG connection.

Comment: Reset Laptop and reinstalled Google Android ADB / Fastboot drivers.

Nexus 5 Phone is detected by ADB & Fastboot.
Nexus 7 2013 Tablet is only detected by ADB.   Need to work out why fastboot is not detected on the Nexus 7. At least I know it's not the tablet or OTG cable as they work with the 5.